# SQLupdate on multiple lines with common part

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help on a table I want to update

My current table `running_purchase`:

```
Today       My_purchase    My_Product   delivery_day    day_late    late_bool
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-04-19  0000001        123456       2017-04-15      4           1 
2017-04-19  0000001        234567       2017-04-20      0           0
2017-04-19  0000001        345678       2017-04-20      0           0
2017-04-19  0000002        456789       2017-04-18      1           1
2017-04-19  0000002        567891       2017-05-15      0           0
2017-04-19  0000003        678912       2017-04-18      1           1
2017-04-19  0000003        789123       2017-04-24      0           0
```

My desired table `running_purchase`:

```
Today       My_purchase    My_Product   delivery_day    day_late    late_bool
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-04-19  0000001        123456       2017-04-15      4           1 
2017-04-19  0000001        234567       2017-04-20      0           1
2017-04-19  0000001        345678       2017-04-20      0           1
2017-04-19  0000002        456789       2017-04-18      1           1
2017-04-19  0000002        567891       2017-05-15      0           1
2017-04-19  0000003        678912       2017-04-18      1           1
2017-04-19  0000003        789123       2017-04-24      0           1
```

Because one product is late the purchase is late.

Is there any request possible in SQL that can change that ?

This is a example, there is about 5k rows per day

I tried with join on `My_purchase` and that did not quite hit the mark.

Thanks in advance

Comment: JOIN can fix it. Show us your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LEFT JOIN`

```
DECLARE @running_purchase AS TABLE
(
   Today date,
   My_purchase varchar(10),
   MyProduct int,
   delivery_day datetime,
   day_late int,
   late_bool bit
)

INSERT INTO @running_purchase
VALUES
('2017-04-19',  '0000001',       123456,     '2017-04-15',     4,          1),
('2017-04-19',  '0000001',       234567,     '2017-04-20',     0,          0),
('2017-04-19',  '0000001',       345678,     '2017-04-20',     0,          0),
('2017-04-19',  '0000002',       456789,     '2017-04-18',     1,          1),
('2017-04-19',  '0000002',       567891,     '2017-05-15',     0,          0),
('2017-04-19',  '0000003',       678912,     '2017-04-18',     1,          1),
('2017-04-19',  '0000003',       789123,     '2017-04-24',     0,          0)

SELECT DISTINCT 
      rp1.Today,rp1.My_purchase,
      rp1.My_purchase,rp1.delivery_day,rp1.day_late, 
      coalesce(rp2.late_bool, 0) AS latebool
FROM @running_purchase rp1
LEFT JOIN @running_purchase rp2 ON rp1.My_purchase = rp2.My_purchase AND rp2.late_bool = 1
```

Or Update

```
UPDATE rp1
SET rp1.late_bool = coalesce(rp2.late_bool, 0) 
FROM @running_purchase rp1
LEFT JOIN @running_purchase rp2 ON rp1.My_purchase = rp2.My_purchase AND rp2.late_bool = 1
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/CQKISJ64546)

Comment: thanks, I needed the update and it worked so well, a huge thanks. I did not know difference between join, left join and all others. did not know the coalesce function too. THX

Comment: You could read some reference links for `join`:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: And `coalesce`: Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using window functions:

```
select rp.*,
       (case when max(rp.day_late) over (partition by rp.my_purchase) > 0
             then 1 else 0
        end) as late_bool
from running_purchase rp;
```

In general, window functions have better performance than other alternatives for arriving at the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This method will work too

```
SELECT *,ISNULL((   SELECT TOP 1 1 
                    FROM running_purchase 
                    WHERE day_late > 0 AND My_Product = p.My_Product),0)    AS late_bool
FROM running_purchase p
```